# How to have Numbers automatically sort descending?

Tags: ipad, numbers, ipados

I’m trying to make my own Sports latter in iPadOS Numbers. I have noticed that there’s an option to sort cells by ascending or descending but I have to click on that option every time I want to update the latter.

Is there a way to have the table automatically sorted based on a certain order?

[image: Numbers not automatically sorting]

[image: Sorting Options]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic re-sorting is not possible with Numbers. However, you can avoid choosing your preferred order every time by creating a sorting rule and then using the Sort Now menu option in iPadOS Numbers as follows:

To create a sorting rule:

1. Select a table to sort, or select just specific rows in a column to sort.
2. Tap the Organize [image: organize button in iPadOS Numbers] button, tap the Sort tab, then tap Entire Table or Selected Rows.
3. Tap Add a Column, then tap a column to sort by.
4. By default, the column sorts in ascending order. To change this, tap the rule in green below the column name.
5. Tap Done.

To apply a sorting rule:

1. Activate the table to be sorted by tapping anywhere on that table.
2. Tap the Organize [image: organize button in iPadOS Numbers] button, tap the Sort tab, and then tap Sort Now.
3. Tap Done to go back to the table which should have been been sorted now as specified in the rule.

For more, see the "[Sort table data in Numbers on iPad](https://support.apple.com/guide/numbers-ipad/alphabetize-or-sort-data-in-a-table-tan192004622/ipados)" Apple support webpage.

Comment: That’s a lot more convenient then what I was doing, though I was hoping for an option that automatically sorts after I’ve adder more numbers similar to how cells numbers can be automatically added.

Comment: Automatic resorting is not possible in Numbers.

Comment: can you leave that as an answer? or add that to your existing answer so I can except it?

Comment: I added the info on automatic re-sorting to my answer. Thx.